# Different output based on console window width

Tags: r, console, window, width

I came across a strange behavior of my R console, although it is probably me who made it do something strange rather than a bug.

When capturing the output of a model (let's say a regression model as in the example below) and saving it to a data frame to make it amendable, and when subsetting a certain amount of rows I am interested in, I will get different results depending on the window width of my console in RStudio.

This would be a minimal working example:

```
> x <- c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)
> y <- c(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
> 
> model <- lm(y ~ x)       # Basic regression model
> output <- summary(model) # Saving the summary
> output

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 2.725e-16 -2.477e-16 -2.484e-17 -2.484e-17  1.242e-17  1.242e-17 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.000e+00  1.195e-16  8.367e+15   <2e-16 ***
x           -1.000e+00  1.852e-16 -5.401e+15   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.852e-16 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 2.917e+31 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> op2 <- capture.output(output) # Capturing the the summary to make it amendable
> op2  <- data.frame(op2)       # Saving the ammendable summary as data frame
> op2
                                                                  op2
1                                                                    
2                                                               Call:
3                                                 lm(formula = y ~ x)
4                                                                    
5                                                          Residuals:
6           1          2          3          4          5          6 
7   2.725e-16 -2.477e-16 -2.484e-17 -2.484e-17  1.242e-17  1.242e-17 
8                                                                    
9                                                       Coefficients:
10                        Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
11          (Intercept)  1.000e+00  1.195e-16  8.367e+15   <2e-16 ***
12          x           -1.000e+00  1.852e-16 -5.401e+15   <2e-16 ***
13                                                                ---
14     Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
15                                                                   
16         Residual standard error: 1.852e-16 on 4 degrees of freedom
17           Multiple R-squared:      1,\tAdjusted R-squared:      1 
18          F-statistic: 2.917e+31 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
19                                                                   
> op3 <- op2[9:14,] # I'm only interested in rows 9 to 14 of the summary, so I subset them
> op3               # And printing them works just fine
[1] "Coefficients:"                                                 
[2] "              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    "     
[3] "(Intercept)  1.000e+00  1.195e-16  8.367e+15   <2e-16 ***"     
[4] "x           -1.000e+00  1.852e-16 -5.401e+15   <2e-16 ***"     
[5] "---"                                                           
[6] "Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1"
```

Now, if I reduce the width of my console (which I have set on the top right of my RStudio) and run the code again from `op2` onwards, I will get a different result because the row numbers of `op2` have changed since they seem dependent on the width of the console.

Like this:

```
> op2 <- capture.output(output)
> op2  <- data.frame(op2)
> op2
                                                          op2
1                                                            
2                                                       Call:
3                                         lm(formula = y ~ x)
4                                                            
5                                                  Residuals:
6                                    1          2          3 
7                            2.725e-16 -2.477e-16 -2.484e-17 
8                                    4          5          6 
9                           -2.484e-17  1.242e-17  1.242e-17 
10                                                           
11                                              Coefficients:
12                                                   Estimate
13                                     (Intercept)  1.000e+00
14                                     x           -1.000e+00
15                                                 Std. Error
16                                     (Intercept)  1.195e-16
17                                     x            1.852e-16
18                                           t value Pr(>|t|)
19                            (Intercept)  8.367e+15   <2e-16
20                            x           -5.401e+15   <2e-16
21                                                           
22                                            (Intercept) ***
23                                            x           ***
24                                                        ---
25                                           Signif. codes:  
26                                0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’
27                                         0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
28                                                           
29 Residual standard error: 1.852e-16 on 4 degrees of freedom
30   Multiple R-squared:      1,\tAdjusted R-squared:      1 
31  F-statistic: 2.917e+31 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
32                                                           

> op3 <- op2[9:14,]
> op3
[1] "-2.484e-17  1.242e-17  1.242e-17 "
[2] ""                                 
[3] "Coefficients:"                    
[4] "              Estimate"           
[5] "(Intercept)  1.000e+00"           
[6] "x           -1.000e+00"
```

Any idea on (i) why the row numbers of `op2` are dependent on the width of my console and (ii) how to avoid this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're explicitly capturing the printed output (which is dependent on screen width) of a summary instead of capturing the stats itself from the model. Is there a reason you can't use the named elements e.g., `summary(.)$coefficients`?

Comment: fyi, this has nothing to do with the RStudio IDE itself, removing the [tag:rstudio] tag

Comment: It does seem odd to use `capture.output` here. By default everything is `print()`ed to the console and a lot of formatting happens in the `print()` function that's dependent on the width of the console. This is normal and expected. If you are trying to use the non-character version of the object, you should avoid using `capture.output` and get values from the returned object itself.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, which make a lot of sense. How could I then make the values of the returned object itself (e.g. via ```summary(.)$coefficients```) amendable?